# JdbcCursorItemReader how to read different JobParameters other than String

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I've a requirement where it is a dynamic query and JobParameters are build using JobParametersBuilder by setting String, Date, Long etc, but able to read only String values in JdbcCursorItemReader. How can we read other than String in JdbcCursorItemReader so it can be set in PreparedStatement query. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

With a step-scoped bean and a SpEL expression you can inject and use any type of parameter in your query. Here is an example with a non string parameter from [one of the samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/partitionJdbcJob.xml):

```
<bean id="itemReader" scope="step" autowire-candidate="false" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.sample.domain.trade.internal.CustomerCreditRowMapper" />
    </property>
    <property name="queryProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="fromClause" value="CUSTOMER"/>
            <property name="selectClause" value="ID,NAME,CREDIT"/>
            <property name="sortKeys">
                <map>
                    <entry key="ID" value="ASCENDING"/>
                </map>
            </property>
            <property name="whereClause" value="ID &gt;= :minId and ID &lt;= :maxId"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="parameterValues">
        <map>
            <entry key="minId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[minValue]}"/>
            <entry key="maxId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[maxValue]}"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**EDIT: Add example with Java configuration style**

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> personReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['id']}") Long id) {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> itemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    itemReader.setSql("select * from person where id = " + id);
    // set other properties on the reader
    return itemReader;
}
```

Comment: Can we do the same even in Annotation or does it support only the XML based? the reason because Query is so dynamic and not constant, including the Select coulumns

Comment: Yes, that's possible. I added an example of how to do that. HIH.